# Bar button color change on tapping in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I am using following code to show buttons on navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveData:)];
    barButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170/255.0 green:210/255.0 blue:87/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    barButton.tag = 001;
    [buttonArray addObject:barButton];
```

This code working fine on iOS 5 and 6. But on iOS 7 button taking the navigation bar color.
Once I tap on any button then, all buttons color changes to tint color.

I searched many hours but not able to find a solution.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: I am able to resolve this bug.                                           
I used a background image for the navigation bar and I used the BarButton color as the navigationbar tint color.

I used following code:
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarBackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 0):

try to do the below:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170/255.0 green:210/255.0 blue:87/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

In iOS7 you need to set `tintColor` to change the bar button tint.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this bug. I used a background image for the navigation bar and I used the BarButton color as the navigationbar tint color. I used following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarBackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

// Bar button Normal State title color.

```
[cancelBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont normalStateFont]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Bar button Highlighted State title color.
[cancelBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont yourHighlightedFont]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```